# A more elegant way to dynamically get generic Action<> type by parameter count?

Tags: c#, reflection

At the moment I'm doing this (//edit: which is totally stupid as there's array which consequentily numbers its items in the same way that I did my Dictionary yesterday):

```
    Dictionary<int, Type> genericMap = new Dictionary<int, Type>
        {
            { 0, typeof(Action) },
            { 1, typeof(Action<>) },
            { 2, typeof(Action<,>) },
            { 3, typeof(Action<,,>) },
            { 4, typeof(Action<,,,>) },
            { 5, typeof(Action<,,,,>) },
            { 6, typeof(Action<,,,,,>) },
            { 7, typeof(Action<,,,,,,>) },
            { 8, typeof(Action<,,,,,,,>) },
        };
```

And somewhere else...

```
var parms = meth.GetParameters();
dType = genericMap[parms.Length].MakeGenericType(parms.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
```

where meth is a MethodInfo.

Is there a more elegant way to do that? Or do I have to define a map like this to get the correct Action<> type dynamically that corresponds to the parameter count?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the purpose. If given a better idea of the larger problem you are trying to solve would be more likely to produce a quality answer for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**:

BTW, Do you know of [`Expression.GetActionType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getactiontype.aspx)?

> Creates a Type object that represents a generic System.Action delegate
>   type that has specific type arguments.

Using that method, you could do:

```
dType = Expression.GetActionType( parms.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray() );
```

---

Other ways:

```
var parms = meth.GetParameters();

int numArgs = parms.Length;

if(numArgs == 0)
{
    dType = typeof(Action);
}    
else 
{
   var rawType = Type.GetType("System.Action`" + numArgs);
   dType = rawType.MakeGenericType(parms.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
}
```

But there's really nothing wrong with your approach really; being as explicit as possibile is often a better choice when it comes to reflection.

Also, here's another fancy way of building your map:

```
typeof(Action).Assembly
              .GetExportedTypes()
              .Where(type => type.FullName.StartsWith("System.Action") 
                                  && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)))
              .ToDictionary(type => type.GetGenericArguments().Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array instead of dictionary, it's actually numbered from 0 to 8, just use array of types and access them with the index.

Comment: Aside from the fact that Ani's answer solves my problem perfectly, this is a classic case of self-facepalm: obviously I was so much in a hurry, yesterday, that I missed the forest for the trees... Thanks for this illuminating insight!